# Cisco ASA 9.1: Asymmetric NAT rules matched for forward and reverse flows (rpf)

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

Can someone explain why the first NAT config below gives me an "asymmetric NAT rules" (RPF) error for the connection to "VPN1" while the second (no "any" in the Manual NAT) makes the automatic NAT actually work?

Automatic NAT (section 2) not working ("asymmetric NAT"):

```
nat (Transit,Internet) source dynamic FW1 interface
!
object network FW1
 host 172.1.2.3
object network VPN1
 nat (Main,Internet) static interface service udp 1194 1195 
!
...
```

This seems to work ok: (explicit destination set for manual NAT in section 1)

```
nat (Transit,Internet) source dynamic FW1 interface destination static DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51
!
object network FW1
 host 172.1.2.3
object network VPN1
 nat (Main,Internet) static interface service udp 1194 1195 
!
...
```

Why does this make a difference for the NAT of VPN1? I don't get it. There are different (source) interfaces involved, different source addresses obviously, so why would one prevent the other from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your two Manual NAT statements is one of them also looks for a match on the *destination* (or *source* on return or outside-originated traffic).

If you convert your NAT statements to 'layman' explanation, it will make more sense.

For example:

```
nat (Transit,Internet) source dynamic FW1 interface
```

When the ASA finds traffic on the `Transit` interface that matches a source of `FW1`, send it to the `Internet` interface and change the *source* `dynamically` to the `interface` IP of the `Internet` interface.

```
nat (Transit,Internet) source dynamic FW1 interface destination static DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51 DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51
```

When the ASA finds traffic on the `Transit` interface that matches a source of `FW1` **and a destination of `DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51`**, send it to the `Internet` interface and change the *source* `dynamically` to the `interface` IP of the `Internet` interface **and change the *destination* `statically` to `DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51`**.

The difference is crucial:

The second NAT statement only matches when `FW1` is speaking to `DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51`. The first NAT statement matches *any time `FW1` is speaking.*

As a result, all your **inbound** traffic (ie: crossing interfaces `Internet` to `Transit`) will have *return traffic* that matches your first NAT statement. Hence, the NAT is asymmetric -- the configuration treats the traffic coming inbound differently than it does on its way out (in so far as NAT).

Remember, this is a Dynamic NAT (also known as a PAT), which by definition can only be unidirectional. Traffic will flow from inside to outside (or `Transit` to `Internet`) but not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah but the question was: why would this difference between the two manual NATs make the NAT between Main<->Internet have differently?

Comment: @Marki What is *Main* in your question? Because I feel I answered the question highlighting the difference between the two configurations. One is NATing (and therefore tring to unNAT) *everything* sent from the object named `FW1`. The other is only NATing (and unNATing) when `FW1` is speaking to `DM_INLINE_NETWORK_51`.  If you could elaborate on what you are missing, maybe I could help out further.

Comment: I was asking why changing the NAT for host FW1 influences that NAT that happens for host VPN1. If the NAT of FW1 is to "any" then the ASA complains that there if an asymmetric flow for the NAT of VPN1. If the NAT to FW1 has a specific destination set, the NAT of VPN1 works ok.

Comment: "Transit", "Main" and "Internet" are 3 interfaces of the ASA.

Comment: @Marki Could you also post the object definition of `FW1` ?

Comment: Done. It's a plain IP address

Comment: @Marki I'm also not seeing the object definition for `VPN1`. The more you can post of your config the better.

Comment: I have edited the question with the info you wanted. Maybe it's waiting for moderation... i'm copying here: `object network FW1
 host 172.1.2.3`